# What was the smaller trophy that Djokovic received after winning the 2023 French Open?

Tags: tennis, awards, grand-slam

During the trophy presentation for the 2023 French Open, Novak Djokovic received the official trophy for winning the tournament. Right after that, a girl walked up to him and gave him a much smaller trophy. What was the smaller trophy for?

Comment: I wonder whether it was some prize for breaking Rafael Nadal's record of 22 Grand Slams (that was Djokovic's 23rd).

Comment: Do you have a video or a photo?  I re-watched the presentation and didn't see anything similar to that.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Did you watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lofDrQVG-yY) of the presentation? If so, notice the video is edited at 0:50 - they skip over the part where he receives the smaller trophy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to an [article](https://en.as.com/other_sports/roland-garros-trophy-what-is-it-called-what-is-it-made-of-why-does-nadal-own-one-n/), the small trophy commemorated his 3 French Open victories:

> Novak Djokovic grabs a special trophy given for his 3 victories at Roland Garros.

It included a photo of the trophy, which you can see has "2016", "2021", and "2023" engraved on it, which are the 3 years in which he has won the French Open so far.

[image]

Comment: An answer was posted (now deleted) that the smaller trophy actually commemorates each of his 23 Grand Slams, with one Grand Slam per side. That is, one side of the small trophy lists his 3 French Open titles by year, another side lists his 10 Australian Open titles by year, another side lists his 7 Wimbledon titles by year, and the last side lists his 3 US Open titles by year. The answer did not provide any citation for that, but I think that makes more sense than just commemorating his 3 French Open titles (which is a far cry from Nadal's 14 French Open titles).

Comment: It also means the [article](https://www.dailyrepublic.com/all-dr-news/sports/professional-sports/major-league-baseball/djokovic-wins-french-open-for-record-23rd-grand-slam-trophy/) that I linked to in the first version of my answer was not incorrect when it said Djokovic received "a small trophy with all his 23 titles engraved".